# Problems with placing variables into a formula and having it advance row by row

Tags: excel, vba, variables, formula

I am pulling numbers from a table (based on day of week) and using it in a formula that multiplies the value by the value of another cell. The day of week formula should advance down by row as should the multiplier cell. The formula needs to copy down 18 times.

I've tried to implement various arrays and loops but I can't seem to get it to advance as needed.

'Identify the correct column

```
Dim pcDOW As Integer 'Day of Week
Dim pcVal As Double     'value for formula

pcDOW = Weekday(Range("k28"))   'I want to make this into a variable or be able to offset

'Look for a match to the weekday to get the correct column

Dim cell As Range
Set cell = Range("b26:h26").Find(pcDOW, LookIn:=xlValues)

pcVal = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value

Range("l29").Formula = "=sum(" & pcVal & "*$l3)"
```

'Works to this point for single value.

I need the `pcVal` to advance one row for each iteration. I keep getting errors. Sorry I'm a beginner with VBA and am still confused about the cells vs range and plugging variables into formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like that will help:

```
Dim lngCount As Long

For lngCount = 1 To 18
    pcVal = cell.Offset(lngCount, 0).Value
    Range("l" & 29 + lngCount - 1).Formula = "=sum(" & pcVal & "*$l3)"
Next lngCount
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code returns a range:

```
   Set findRange = Range("b26:h26").Find(pcDOW, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

You should iterate over the range:

```
For Each c In findRange.Cells
 pcVal = c
... your code
Next c
```

Comment: The issue isn't iterating through the find range. Once the column is identified by the find the data begins in the next cell down (hence the offset) and then I need to iterate down through that, as well as iterate down the column I am putting the formula in.

Comment: Can u provide a sample with data?

Comment: I can't copy and paste. columns are 1 through 7 and contain values:  0.37  0.40  0.39  0.41  0.40  0.40  0.38    then the next row contains  0.35  0.36  0.38 etc. My formula starts in L28 and needs to use the .37 then in L29 use 0.35, etc.